# Script Slicing in Python

Tags: python, slice

I am new in programming and Python. 
I have a list in my hand and I want to manipulate my list as each words will be consisted of (first) 6 letters maximum.

Sample list as below.

```
 new_list = ['partiye', 'oy', 'vermeyecegimi', 'bilerek', 'sandiga', 'gidecegim']
```

I used below code for cutting the words.

```
 s = []
 a = []
 for i in range(len(new_list)):
      s = new_list[i]
      for j in new_list:
           a = s[:6]     
 print a
```

Each words consist of max 6 letters. The output of the code is "partiy
     oy
     vermey
     bilere
     sandig
     gidece".

But I could not assign my updated (cutted) words into a new list. Can someone advise me how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where list comprehensions become really handy:

```
>>> new_list = ['partiye', 'oy', 'vermeyecegimi', 'bilerek', 'sandiga', 'gidecegim']
>>> print [i[:6] for i in new_list]
['partiy', 'oy', 'vermey', 'bilere', 'sandig', 'gidece']
```

If you wanted to expand it:

```
s = []
for i in new_list:
    s.append(i[:6])
```

It's pretty much the same approach as what you're doing, but it's a little neater.

What you're doing is continually re-assigning `a` to a value so it's rather pointless. I think you wanted `a.append(s[:6])` anyway, which adds a value to a list, but even then that won't work since you're approaching the solution the wrong way :p.

Comment: Terry, but the list is not updated. new_list is still as below isn't it ? I also want to update my list as each words will be max 6 letters. 'code' >>> new_list = ['partiye', 'oy', 'vermeyecegimi', 'bilerek', 'sandiga', 'gidecegim']

Comment: @Behzat That's because the list comprehension does not override the list, you need to do that. This is easily obtained by doing `new_list = [i[:6] for i in new_list]`

Comment: Many thanks Terry. That's what I try to do. It works very well.